# Use SQL or NoSQL?

Tags: sql, database, nosql

I'm designing a system that checks a given website for any security vulnerabilities. The system includes a client (firefox plugin) and a server. The server does all the scanning while the client just relays that info to the user. If a website is dangerous, it is blacklisted; otherwise whitelisted.

The system must hypothetically be able to handle several thousands of requests and updates to the database simultaneously.

Although the database is expected to have a very simple structure, I am still considering using NoSQL because my understanding is that it can handle a greater amount of queries. Is this true? Which db technology is better suited for my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a NoSQL database.

In fact I've been working with two databases in the last weeks, and searching on internet I found the differences between a NoSQL an a SQL database.

Pratically, you should use a NoSQL db if you have a lot of data to query. Remind that it's not sure the data recovery in case of a db disaster.

Instead, use a SQL database if your data MUST be permanent, and you can't lose it. But query times will be longer, so it's not suggested if you have tons of data.

I understood, from what you wrote, that you need lot of queries and you "can lose" the data (if you lose a website of the list, you'll just need to re-check it, right?).
So I suggest you to go for a NoSQL db (I worked with MongoDb, it is the most famous worl-wide).

Comment: Thanks. A NoSQL db it is then :)

Comment: need to wait 2 mins ;)

Comment: Oh sorry :) also MongoDb is really easy to use

Answer (score 0):

If you consider NoSQL Databases you have to analyze your data to get the right Database.

For your use case I think you should look at document databases (like MongoDB) or, if you want really high performance, a key-value Database like Redis or Riak.

With Key-Value databases you can only use the key to find the data you want.

With document databases you still have some kind of querys to find the data.

For further information look at: http://nosql-database.org/